# FluentAssertions: use Should().NotThrow() on async method

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

Is use **c# FluentAssertions** and I want to assert if i given **async** method does not throw an exception. 
Given a synchronous method, fluent assertions libray allows me to assert like this

```
 Action action = () => YourSynchronousMethod();
 action.Should().NotThrow<Exception>();
```

Can I do the same for **async** methods?

Comment: Does `Func<Task> f = async () => { await YourAsynchronousMethod(); };` and `f.Should().NotThrow<Exception>()` work?

Comment: Bear in mind - `async` is an *implementation detail* of a method. Not part of it's signature. What you actually care about is making fluent assertions about *`Task` returning methods*, searching for which brought me to the suggested duplicate.